# JMS Transaction Rollback Property not working in WSO2 4.8.1 ESB

Tags: transactions, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I have made a simple proxy service which is listening a XML message from a JMS Queue (based on ActiveMQ) and doing some transformation on it. I want to implement JMS Transaction Rollback property so if any error or exception occur during the transformation the message would RollBack.

**Problem:**

I have followed the [official](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JMS+Transactions) instructions but it is not working. When any exception occurs the message won't roll back. Exception is logged but message is lost.

**Proxy Service SourceCode:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JMSGateway"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <xslt key="conf:/xslt/ConvertToCDM.xslt">
            <resource location="conf:xslt/ConvertToCDM.xslt" key="ConvertToCDM"/>
         </xslt>
         <log level="full"/>
         <log/>

      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_DETAIL" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_EXCEPTION" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
            <property name="File_Name" expression="get-property('Received.File.Name')"/>
            <property name="Transaction Action" value="Rollbacked"/>
         </log>

      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/xml</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">CDMRequest</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add thoses parameters to your proxy def :

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
```

If you can see your error log more than one time, then the message has been redelivered by ActiveMQ and you know that your ESB conf is correct (rollback with SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY=true is effective)

After a few times, depending on ActiveMQ conf, the message should be removed from the queue and moved to a Dead Letter Queue.

If the message is lost, you should have a look at ActiveMQ configuration (see http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html)

You could focus on the fact that non-persisted message are not sent to DLQ but removed. If you want to change this behaviour, modify ActiveMQ conf :

```
<broker...>
  <destinationPolicy>
   <policyMap>
     <policyEntries>
       <!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
       <policyEntry queue=">">
         <!-- 
           Tell the dead letter strategy to also place non-persisted messages 
           onto the dead-letter queue if they can't be delivered.
         -->
         <deadLetterStrategy>
           <sharedDeadLetterStrategy processNonPersistent="true" />
         </deadLetterStrategy>
       </policyEntry>
     </policyEntries>
   </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
...
</broker>
```

Comment: when you try it, you have an exception inside inSequence mediation and you can see the log "Transaction Action=Rollbacked" from the faultSequence ? And your message is lost : no message in CDMRequest queue, no message in ActiveMQ.DLQ ?

Comment: The service goes into fault sequence and yes i see the "Transaction Action=Rollbacked" tag but the message is lost.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment but all the messages that my service is producing are "persistent" and still they are not going into ActiveMQ.DLQ.....

Comment: are they redelivered by ActiveMQ (can you see for one message sent to your JMS queue, more than one log trace "Transaction Action=Rollbacked") ? In that case, there is a transaction and you must focus on ActiveMQ config. In the other case, there is no transaction and you must focus on your conf in WSO2

Comment: well there is no repetition in the logs so i think i have to focus on conf in WSO2.

Comment: i added following properties in axis2.xml file in WSO2 and it worked.

Comment: <parameter name="transport.Transactionality" locked="true">local</parameter>
             <parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries" locked="true">-1</parameter>
   <parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay" locked="true">60000</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel" locked="true">consumer</parameter>

Comment: Strange, I'm using ActiveMQ 5.9 and don't need thoses parameters, my conf in axis2.xml : <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>    I just need the 2 parameters given in my answer, in my proxy def